# Range search with file name and numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I indexed all my files in Elasticsearch and I want to do a range search on the filename. The filename are currently stored as text and keyword, but I'm open to change the mapping.

In some cases, I have files that are name: image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg,...,image-200.jpg.

I would like to be able to get all the files that are between image-1.jpg to image-9.jpg.

I'm currently using the following request to get those files:

```
GET /file/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "filename": {
                 "from": "image-1",
                 "to": "image-1"
            }
         }
     }
}
```

The output should be 9 images:
`image-1.jpg, image-2.jpg,..., image-9.jpg`

But I also get result like:
`image-21.jpg, image-22.jpg, image-23.jpg, image-30.jpg, ...`

Is there a query or a mapping to fix my issue?

Comment: I would probably store the index of the file (1, 2, 3, 4, ...) into another field and do the range query on that field. Much easier than trying to do it on strings

Comment: Yes It's exactly what I will do. Thanks.